# Azure Functions Event hub read write latency spikes with StorageException and SocketException spikes

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-eventhub

We have a service in production that is suffering from Latency spikes. During these spikes we see we are getting a large amount of StorageExceptions and SocketExceptions
[image]

[image: error count table]

These images are over a 4 hour time period.

What more is, this only happens on our EUS instance of the service (which has approximetly 26 event hub triggers) and not on our WEU (7 event hub triggers) and Canary(EUS2 - 2 event hub triggers).

The innermost error for the storage account exceptions we are seeing is:
A lease ID was specified, but the lease for the blob has expired.
which is known to be OK in small amounts - but 24.5K in 4 hours doesnt feel like small amounts and there is a direct correlation between the exception spikes and the latency spikes

The innermost exception for the sockets is:
An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
It also correlates nicely to the latency spikes.

On the other hand events can be seen flowing through the service and to the receiving event hub through the entire 4 hour time period:
[image]

All the outgoing events are written to the same event hub in every cloud (3 total - 1 EUS, 1EUS2, 1WEU), where every cloud writes to its own eventhub accordingly.
It also seems that the entire latency spike is due to the write action to the eventhub (which is done via eventhub name + FQDN AAD connection):
[image]

Any help with this issue will be much appreciated!

Comment: Regarding lease issues; refrain from using the same eventhub names across regions. I have seen customers misconfiguring their consumers due to identical names.

Regarding timeouts, is storage account in the same region as the function app?

Comment: Hi @SerkantKaraca, thanks for the input!
We are reading from different event hub namespaces dependent on the region they are located but writing to the same event hub namespace for each cloud.
The cloud level eventhub namespaces we are writing to also have different names from one another.
This may have not been clear from the original message - all the event hubs are uniquely named.
As for the second part - the StorageAccount, AzureFunction and EventHubNamespace (we are writing to) are all located in the same region and the same resource group.

Comment: Can you make sure sink Event Hubs namespace has enough TU allocated to handle the writes? And also, how do you write to EH? Are you using output binding or creating an EH client in the code?

Comment: @SerkantKaraca, The default TU is set to 1 but I have auto inflate set to 20 (which is the max).
We are creating the EventHubProducerClient in the code using an AAD (EH name + FQDN) style connection. The EventHubProducerClient created is set in a singleton static context.

Comment: I changed the default TU to 20 just to see if its due to auto inflate reaction time but I still get the same spikes in latency (and the same spikes in exceptions)

Comment: What is the peak ingress on the sink namespace? In both number of messages and bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We resolved the issue -
The Azure function was set on a consumption plan - this set it so there was only one instance available. To increase to more than one instance I would need to change the plan from consumption to premium.

In addition to this I discovered that on startup the function creates connections with all Eventhubs for all the triggers - in this case 26 Eventhubs.
Each Eventhub has 32 partitions so that's 32 connections per Eventhub.

Azure functions on consumption plan have a hard limit of 600 connections.

This meant that once the connections were established it would eventually reach its 600 limit, enter an unhealthy state and restart itself which in turn created the latency spikes because of startup and handling of backlogged events from the hub.

Upgrading from consumption to premium allowed a higher limit of connections and adding an additional instance (increasing the min instances running from 1 to 2) which split the connections opened between the instances so we didn't reach the lower limit.

Hope this helps anyone else stuck with this.